# For `concept A = ...;`, should `requires A` and `requires (A)` be identical?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

The discussion first takes place at [llvm/llvm-project#60377](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60377). After reading [temp.constr.atomic](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#atomic) and [temp.constr.normal](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#normal) again and again, I feel even more confused about this question beacause of my poor English.

Like the example below, in order to help clang-format format requires clause correctly, I used to add a pair of bracket. Now I changed my style. When I tried to change my code, the unexpected error happened.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
  requires std::integral<T>
struct [[nodiscard]] Widget;

template <typename T>
  requires(std::integral<T>)  // error: Requires clause differs
struct [[nodiscard]] Widget {
  T value;
};

[[nodiscard]] auto main() -> int {
  Widget<int> widget{1};
  return widget.value;
}
```

I tested this with different compilers. It turns out:

- [error - x86_64 clang (trunk)](https://godbolt.org/z/6xTGY77cz)
- [pass - x86_64 gcc (trunk)](https://godbolt.org/z/xoM1M8Mvr)
- [error - x64 msvc v19.latest](https://godbolt.org/z/dcrYo3q7f)

What is the expected behaviour according to the standard, clang/msvc or gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the expected behaviour according to the standard, clang/msvc or gcc?

The standard does not require any particular behaviour (C++23 CD [intro.compliance.general] paragraph 2). The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required because the validity of the program depends on whether or not the *template-head*s are equivalent ([basic.link] paragraph 11) and they are functionally equivalent but not equivalent ([temp.over.link] paragraph 7).